# Python2 faster than Python3 for selecting data in pandas DataFrame...why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

We are noticing alot of slow down in our production system after switching from python2 to python3.  We were able to isolate the majority of a slowdown to the line below...a selection of rows from a pandas dataFrame that we use for windowing signals.

```
ix = ts[(ts >= start) & (ts <= stop)].index.tolist()
```

When we run the same code in Python2.7.12 (pandas 0.17.0) and Python3.5.2 (pandas 0.23.3)...we get different speeds.  Python3 takes almost twice as long. (on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 VM, Python2=14.9sec vs Python3=28.4sec)

Any ideas on why this is happening?  or any ideas on how we could recover some speed?

Here is a code snippet that we used to test the speed:

```
import os
import pandas
import timeit

ts_df = pandas.DataFrame([[1.032,3.480653,-1,2.448653],
[3.480653,3.792538,0,0.311886],
[3.792538,12.022123,1,8.229585],
[12.022123,21.91544,0,9.893317],
[21.91544,23.850186,-1,1.934746],
[23.850186,26.495987,0,2.6458],
[26.495987,30.09994,1,3.603953],
[30.09994,31.679636,0,1.579696],
[31.679636,33.491384,-1,1.811748],
[33.491384,35.549925,0,2.058541],
[35.549925,37.267455,-1,1.71753],
[37.267455,37.665347,0,0.397893],
[37.665347,40.038281,1,2.372933],
[40.038281,40.292786,0,0.254505],
[40.292786,43.168465,-1,2.875679],
[43.168465,46.916554,0,3.74809],
[46.916554,48.510315,1,1.593761],
[48.510315,61.023221,0,12.512907],
[61.023221,61.426129,-1,0.402908],
[61.426129,63.271943,0,1.845813],
[63.271943,66.097349,1,2.825406],
[66.097349,68.298797,0,2.201448],
[68.298797,70.465333,1,2.166536],
[70.465333,77.336305,0,6.870972],
[77.336305,85.306432,1,7.970127],
[85.306432,87.363149,0,2.056717],
[87.363149,90.143931,-1,2.780782],
[90.143931,90.538878,0,0.394947],
[90.538878,94.289258,1,3.75038],
[94.289258,96.178212,0,1.888954]], columns=['startTimeIndex','stopTimeIndex','value','duration'])

def indexMe1(ts, start, stop):
    ts = ts['startTimeIndex']
    ix = ts[(ts >= start) & (ts <= stop)].index.tolist()
    return ix

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('indexMe1:')
    print(indexMe1(ts_df, 5, 22))
    print(timeit.timeit("indexMe1(ts_df, 5, 22)",
                        setup="from __main__ import indexMe1, ts_df",
                        number=10000))
```

Comment: The implementation of timeit changed between python 2 and 3 iirc. Are you sure you compare apples to apples?

Comment: @JanMatějka - we are seeing this in our production log files as well by looking at the log times.  I just did the timeit example to make it easier for others to reproduce.  But will take any suggestions on how to make more apples to apples.

Comment: I am actually seeing huge improvement in py3 vs py2. 882 usec per loop vs 279 usec per loop. Using different version of pandas tho (1.1.0 and  0.24.2, respectively) and python 3.7.3. I'd try to update the python and pandas versions to see if there is a difference.

Comment: I've run the snippet in ubuntu 16.04 docker image against the same pandas version (0.17.1) and am getting the same results, so I'd look into the pandas version difference.

Comment: How did you get pandas 0.23.3 into python 3.5.2?
I get RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.6 required when trying to install it.

Comment: Thanks Jan.  I will try the pandas version change and see what I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jan for working on this!

Answering own question just to document what I found.

In terms of why is this happening...
Found that something in combination of our python and pandas versions was producing a slow up.

In terms of how to recover the speed...
When I moved to python3.8.5 and pandas1.1.0, the slow-up that we saw in python3 went away.